# How do I write x in terms of y in a quartic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a few quartic equations that are in the general form, $$y = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$$Is there any way I can write $x$ in terms of $y$?

For example, one of the equations is: 
$$y = -0.000439x^4 + 0.052x^3 - 1.56x^2 + 17.57x +14.46$$

And I need to separate the $x$ variable. 
Is it possible? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Answer (score -1):

Since y(x) is not generally invertible, there's no closed form for x in terms of y. To show it is not invertible, use the horizontal line test, which fails for some choices of the constants.

Comment: It is never invertible on the full $(-\infty,\infty)$ interval, unless $a=0$ and some other conditions.